# MongoDB aggregation: Add custom fields query which define the order

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

One of my collections is a list of operations with some status. For example, a list of documents can look like this:

```
[
    { _id: '1',status: false},
    {_id: '2', status:false},
    {_id: '3',status: true},
    {_id: '4',status: true},
    {_id: '5',status: true},
    {_id: '6',status: true},
    {_id: '7',status: false},
    {_id: '8',status: false},
]
```

and i want this result:

```
[
    { _id: '1',status: false, order: 1},
    {_id: '2', status:false, order: 1},
    {_id: '3',status: true, order: 2},
    {_id: '4',status: true, order: 2},
    {_id: '5',status: true, order: 2},
    {_id: '6',status: true, order: 2},
    {_id: '7',status: false, order: 3},
    {_id: '8',status: false, order: 3},
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one should work:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      data: { $push: "$$ROOT" } }
  },

  {
    $set: {
      data: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$data",
          initialValue: [],
          in: {
            $cond: {
              if: { $eq: [ "$$this.status", { $last: "$$value.status" } ] },
              then: {
                $concatArrays: [
                  "$$value",
                  [
                    {
                      $mergeObjects: [
                        "$$this",
                        { order: { $last: "$$value.order" } }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                ]
              },
              else: {
                $concatArrays: [
                  "$$value",
                  [
                    {
                      $mergeObjects: [
                        "$$this",
                        {
                          order: {
                            $add: [
                              { $ifNull: [ { $last: "$$value.order" }, 0 ] }, 1 ] } 
                         } 
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$data" },
  { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$data" } }
])
```

See [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ciRcOwzkBHC)

Comment: Nice solution, i just noticed, this returning first document twicely. because there 
is default first document in initialValue and in reduce operation concat arrays with it.

Comment: @turivishal, you are right, I changed to initial value of `[]` - and `$mergeObjects` is better because it is more generic.

Answer (score 0):

This is a way that i know to do your requirement, but might be there will be more efficient way to do this,

- `$group` by null and group all root documents in `root` array, get first document `status` in `firstStatus` field
- `$reduce` to iterate loop of `root` array

  - `initialValue` to initialize 3 fields, `root` empty array, `order` by default 1, `status` is `firstField`
  - `in`, check condition if `status` is match with initial `status` then,

    - operation would be, merge objects with current object and `order` field from initial value using `$mergeObjects`, concat arrays with initial value `root` and above merged objects using `$concatArrays` and pass `order` and `status` field same as initial value
    - else operation would be, for `root` field, `order` to increment number using `$add` and merge objects with current object and `order` field using `$mergeObjects`, concat initial value's `root` field and above merged object as array using `$concatArrays`, `order` field to increment order number to initial value and `status` to update status from current object

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      root: { $push: "$$ROOT" },
      firstStatus: { $first: "$$ROOT.status" }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      root: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$root",
          initialValue: { root: [], order: 1, status: "$firstStatus" },
          in: {
            $cond: [
              { $eq: ["$$this.status", "$$value.status"] },
              {
                root: {
                  $concatArrays: [
                    "$$value.root",
                    [{ $mergeObjects: ["$$this", { order: "$$value.order" }] }]
                  ]
                },
                order: "$$value.order",
                status: "$$value.status"
              },
              {
                root: {
                  $concatArrays: [
                    "$$value.root",
                    [{ $mergeObjects: ["$$this", { order: { $add: ["$$value.order", 1] } }] }]
                  ]
                },
                order: { $add: ["$$value.order", 1] },
                status: "$$this.status"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$root.root" },
  { $replaceWith: "$root.root" }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/SYNEUsV_kwK)